# a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-signin

I'm trying to store data from a my app to Cloud Firestore using Google Authenticator, however I notice every time I try to store the data nothing gets transcribed and i keep on getting an error below:

```
E/flutter ( 9660): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter ( 9660): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter ( 9660): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
   
scaffold.dart:148
E/flutter ( 9660): #6      showSnackBar
utils.dart:4
E/flutter ( 9660): #7      AuthController.signInWithGoogle.<anonymous closure>
auth_controller.dart:42
E/flutter ( 9660): #8      Left.match
either.dart:592
E/flutter ( 9660): #9      Either.fold
either.dart:255
E/flutter ( 9660): #10     AuthController.signInWithGoogle
auth_controller.dart:41
E/flutter ( 9660): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Code below corresponds to the error I've been receiving as per my console:

```dart
void signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context, bool isFromLogin) async {
  state = true;
  final user = await _authRepository.signInWithGoogle(isFromLogin);
  state = false;
  user.fold(
    (l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message),
    (userModel) => _ref.read(userProvider.notifier).update((state) => userModel),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try checking if the context is mounted or not before showing  snackbar.

```dart
void signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context, bool isFromLogin) async {
    state = true;
    final user = await _authRepository.signInWithGoogle(isFromLogin);
    state = false;
    user.fold(
      (l) {
         if(context.mounted){
           showSnackBar(context, l.message);
        },
      (userModel) =>
          _ref.read(userProvider.notifier).update((state) => userModel),
    );
  }
```

Also I will suggest not passing context, instead you can retun result from this method and based on result show snack-bar on widget class.